# Do Area Spells really not affect anyone you can't see?

Tags: spells, magic, shadowrun-sr5

The spellcasting section specifies (emphasis mine):

> Area Spells: Area spells can be cast on a specific target
>   or a point in space that you can see. Unless noted in
>   a spell, the area of the spell is a sphere centered on the
>   target with a radius in meters equal to the Force of the
>   spell. **All targets in the area of effect that you can see,
>   friend and foe alike, are valid targets for the spell. If a potential
>   target is outside your vision (behind a screen, for
>   example), they’re not affected.**

I don't think it make sense that a fireball would just not explode into places you can't see, especially considering the note on indirect spells:

> Indirect spells:
>   [...]
>   So you don’t really need to be able to see the target—you can
>   cast these spells blindfolded or with artificial image enhancement—
>   as long as you’ve got a clear line of fire.
>   [...]

So I was wondering if it only applies to direct damage and effects like illusions and such, and indirect spells like fireballs would affect all targets in its area regardless of whether the caster can see them or not?

Comment: Please do not answer in comments,

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you'll find a definitive answer unless they clarify in the errata, but my impression is this:

Anyone in your line of site can be a target, the focus of the spell; if they are not in your line of site, they cannot be the *target* of the spell.

If you throw a fireball at a guy standing outside a wage-slave's cubicle, chewing him out, then the fireball would effect everything within the radius - walls, papers, computers, the poor unfortunate inside.

If the guy sees you coming, and ducks inside while you're getting ready, then you could no longer target him. But (assuming you're not a dwarf), you could choose the top of the cubicle as the center of your attack, and still hit him with the AoE.

To me, that seems to be the spirit of the rule, even if the wording is ambiguous.

Comment: they mentionned anything about an errata going out soon?

Comment: Nothing that I've seen. They said that they would update it over time, and try to make an announcement when they did so, but I haven't heard much recently.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong as these rules have a history of being unclear, but I was under the impression that the difference lied mostly between physical (fireball) and mana spell (mana ball).

I understood it that physical area spells could be targeted pretty much anywhere in your line of sight, and since they are actually physical in manifestation, they would hit anybody in its area, whereas mana spells actually required that you can provide the "mystical link" hinted at in the magic section to all targets, that need be in the area. That is for mana spells, all targets in the area must be seen to be affected